# Using Java 8 Optional with JSONObject?

Tags: java-8, option-type, json

**GIVEN:**

```
JSONObject o = <populated from json source>;

if (o.has("stuff") && response.getJSONObject("stuff").has("stuffList")  
      && o.getJSONObject("stuff").getJSONArray("stuffList").size() > 0) {
  doStuff()
}
```

**ASK:**
How can I rewrite the above using java.util.Optional so that I don't have to make all those JSONObject checks?

Something like:

```
java.util.Optional<JSONObject> _O = java.util.Optional.ofNullable(o);
java.util.Optional<Integer> size = _response.map(JSONObject::getJSONObject("stuffList")...<etc>???;

if (size.IsPresent && size > 0) { doStuff(); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not refactorable in a nicely way to Optionals in this case.
Why?

*getJSONObject()* method will never return null. If there is no value associated with provided key, it will throw JSONException. Optional monad was designed for handling nulls and not exceptions. Those checks are necessary in this case.

---

However, for educational purposes, let's assume that if there is no value stored under a specified key, method would return null. 
You could refactor it like this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(response.getJSONObject("stuff"))
            .map(stuff -> stuff.getJSONArray("stuffList"))
            .filter(array -> array.length() > 0)
            .ifPresent((array) -> doStuff(array)); // replaceable with a method reference
```

Comment: yeah, that is what i was running up against.  awesome. thank you!